# How can I count the number of lines in my all my files in this directory?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to count the lines of all files in this directory and all its subdirectories, but exclude directories "public", "modules", and "templates".

How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 find . -type f |grep -v "^./public" |grep -v "^./modules"|grep -v "^./templates"|xargs cat |wc -l
```

1. make a list of all files under current directory with `find . -type f`
2. filter out files from "exclude" dirs with grep -v
3. `xargs` will read list of files from stdin and pass all files as options to `cat`.
4. `cat` will print all files to stdout
5. wc will count lines.

If you want to count lines in every file individually, change `xargs cat |wc -l`  to `xargs wc -l`

Comment: Casper's solution is nicer, avoiding the `grep -v`.

Comment: jfgagne, If you consider his solution as better, upvote it. My solution is easier to understand and to modify - I think it is better to begginner. Casper's needs a deep knowledge of the find command, and my needs only basic options of find, grep, xargs, wc.

Comment: Also, `-print0` is unportable, according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html "Other implementations have added other ways to get around this problem, notably a -print0 primary that wrote filenames with a null byte terminator. This was considered here, but not adopted. "

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type d \
  \( -path ./public -o -path ./modules -o -path ./templates \) -prune \
  -o -type -f -print0 | xargs -0 wc
```

Comment: As osgw pointed out, using `-print` and piping to `xargs cat | wc -l` might be more portable, but I like avoiding many greps and avoiding going down uselessly in directories.  If you do not have read permission on those directories, lots of warning are avoided.  +1, and I think it should be the accepted solution.